# is there any standard cpp build system

Tags: c++, c++11, build, makefile, cmake

Is there any build system that is either recommended or mentioned by c++ standard committee? I've tried cmake and found it good but not satisfactory build system.

It generated a tons of files and code for my simple 2 source 1 header file project. Even if I did out of source builds, it filled build directory with insane amounts of code, which I am unsure that a makefile would be comparative in size.

I have searched quite a bit and found Meson, gradle, Ninja, Tupp, Premake, Scons, Shake and ant but I'm more confused now with so many choices. And some of these do replace makefiles I guess while some just create makefiles.

What do you use? and Why?

Comment: For small projects, like less then 3 files total, I don't use a makefile.  Other larger ones, I would use a makefile if there wasn't an IDE available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard committee has no business in recommending a specific build-system, especially when such recommendation rests on comparing potentially commercial products or independent open-source projects.

The question you're asking is primarily opinion-based, but in short, there is no need to use a build-system if your project consists of just a few files, a simple home-made makefile should suffice.

Tools like cmake and Scons (I don't really know anything about the others you mentioned) are designed to handle (very) large projects with arbitrarily complex build-options and dependencies. Again, this shouldn't be of any use to you if you are planning on developing a mid-size software and that you plan on doing it alone, although you might also want to learn to use these tools for later.

I personally (here goes the opinion-based) almost always use my own makefiles, because I only work on unix/linux and that my projects never exceed a few hundred files.